# Некорректные цвета PILLOW paste

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pillow, pil

Вставляю одну фотку в другую данным кодом
`

```
image = Image.open("1.png")
liga = Image.open("0.png")   
image.paste(liga, (100, 100), liga)
image.show()
```

`
У вставляемой картинки "liga" изменяются цвета(фотку приложил)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал сохранить ее "liga" перед вставкой и отображается корректно, пробовал также `liga.convert('RGBA')`, но также просто оттенки меняются. Есть гении?

Comment: А формат картинок после их загрузки в переменные посмотреть? Может он разный какой-то.

Comment: А что этот даст, как с этим можно играть дальше

Comment: Image.save("output.jpg") а просто сохранить пробовали?

Comment: да, результат такой же

Answer (score 0):

Решение:
сделать конвертацию при открытии, а не отдельно

`liga = Image.open("0.png").convert('RGBA')`